# How to change release version in crashlytics?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fastlane, google-fabric, fabric-beta

There are some builds pushed to fabric/crashlytics, but they hold one release version (no idea where taken from) with numerous build numbers. How to change/increment/sync the release version in fastlane?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot?

Comment: sorry no, but the release number is like x.x.x (z) where z is a build number and x.x.x is a release number. I thought that was a standard release convention in beta

Comment: 1. Select your application
2. Go to crashlytics 
3. Under the title “Crashlytics” you will find “Top Builds”(From here you can find your all versions)

Comment: is it work or not for you?

Comment: that is just a filter, I want to change the release version. Should I do that in code or that can be set in fastlane?

Comment: You can not do that with code as they are not allowing, It's just show your latest release version on top of older versions

Comment: so then what determines the incrementation of the x.x.x value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashlytics pulls the version number from the `Info.plist` file in the IPA that fastlane uploads.

You can change the version number in Crashlytics by editing the *Bundle Versions String, Short* entry in your `Info.plist` file prior to building the application. This file is created automatically as part of any iOS application project.

You can also use [the `increment_version_number` fastlane action](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_version_number/) to set it programmatically instead of doing it by hand.